# silverstripe change optgroup color in backend

Tags: css, backend, silverstripe

does anybody know how i can change the color of the  or maybe other css things to make it look much different from the  tags in GroupedDropdownField?
i have tried to change the color by updating the framework/admin/css/screen.css with:

```
select optgroup {color:#f00 !important}
```

but it didnt work

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Do not edit any core files in the *framework* or the *cms* directories. This is not the right place to make changes.

Instead, extend the CMS by adding a required css file.

In Silverstripe 3.1 to have your css file loaded by the CMS, add the following code to your config yml file:

**mysite/_config/config.yml**

```
LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_css:
    - mysite/css/GroupedDropdownField.css
```

Next add your Grouped Dropdown css into the following file:

**mysite/css/GroupedDropdownField.css**

```css
.field .chzn-container .chzn-results li.group-option {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

The reason styling `select optgroup` does not work is because Silverstripe replaces the `select` box with a styled `div` and `ul` list.

If you inspect the elements of the dropdown list you will see the elements that are available to be styled.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify any of the code in framework; all changes will be overwritten whenever you do an upgrade, such as a security update. Instead, [follow this tutorial](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/theme-development) to make a new theme. Make your changes within the theme.

Comment: You might even just make a copy of the "simple" theme and modify your copy.